# Inserting php into my form variable

Tags: php

I have my form within a php variable which is returned later on in the code:

```
$email_form = '<form class="cpd-form store-form" method="post" action="'.get_permalink().'">


        <input type="hidden" id="contact-action" name="contact-action" value="" />
            <div class="your-details group">
            <div class="your-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_name" id="cpdstore-name" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="your-detail end-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_school">School/Department:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_school" id="cpdstore-school" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="your-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_email" id="cpdstore-email" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="your-detail end-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_phone">Phone:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_phone" id="cpdstore-phone" value="" />
                    </div> ...
```

I need to make the form sticky, what and how do i insert a php conditional into the input values?

Comment: what condition do you want to insert? Can you bit more clear in your requirement?

Comment: Whether or not the input has been set, if it has display it in the input value attribute. It's for when the page returns validation errors. Without this the user has to fill in all the values again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_form = '<form class="cpd-form store-form" method="post"  action="'.get_permalink().'">
    <input type="hidden" id="contact-action" name="contact-action" value="" />
        <div class="your-details group">
        <div class="your-detail">
                <label for="cpdstore_name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="cpdstore_name" id="cpdstore-name" value="<?php echo $value1;?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="your-detail end-detail">
                <label for="cpdstore_school">School/Department:</label>
                <input type="text" name="cpdstore_school" id="cpdstore-school" value="<?php echo $value2;?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="your-detail">
                <label for="cpdstore_email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="cpdstore_email" id="cpdstore-email" value="<?php echo $value3;?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="your-detail end-detail">
                <label for="cpdstore_phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="cpdstore_phone" id="cpdstore-phone" value="<?php echo $value4;?>" />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to show a value in input field by default. I am not able to get clear idea from your explanations. But I assume it. If your requirement is actually this, just try the following code.

```
$email_form = '<form class="cpd-form store-form" method="post" action="'.get_permalink().'">

        <input type="hidden" id="contact-action" name="contact-action" value="'.$value1.'" />
            <div class="your-details group">
            <div class="your-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_name" id="cpdstore-name" value="'.$value2.'" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="your-detail end-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_school">School/Department:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_school" id="cpdstore-school" value="'.$value3.'" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="your-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_email" id="cpdstore-email" value="'.$value4.'" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="your-detail end-detail">
                    <label for="cpdstore_phone">Phone:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpdstore_phone" id="cpdstore-phone" value="'.$value5.'" />
                    </div> ...
```

Comment: Woudl this work: value="'. $form_data['cpdstore_name'] ? $form_data['cpdstore_name'] : '' .'"